# ScrollView doesn't work - Android

Tags: android, scrollview, emulation, device

I have spent some time on this, and I can't get the ScrollView to work on my Android App. I'm testing it in a Android Emulator, since i don't have an Android device with me right now. I know it should be a silly problem, but I can't figure it out!

The XML code:

```
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="generalclasses.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/signintextview"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/useridtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usertextview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/usertextview"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hintusuario" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usertextview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:text="@string/usertextview"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signupherebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/signinbutton"
            android:text="@string/signupherebutton" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passwordtextview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/useridtext"
            android:layout_below="@+id/useridtext"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/passwordtextview"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordedittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordtextview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/passwordtextview"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hintsenha"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newheretextview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/signupherebutton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/signupherebutton"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/signinbutton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="@string/newheretextview"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signinbutton"
            style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordedittext"
            android:layout_below="@+id/passwordedittext"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="@string/signinbutton" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: have you tried to move the line tools:context in your scrollView ?

Comment: May be you are tapping on edittext and trying to scroll. If so try to tap somewhere else in layout and try scrolling. Do you have items not visible in the screen, but present in layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is happening becuase you are putting your views inside a RelativeLAyout
put them in LinearLayout and set the orienation to vertical

Comment: set height of linearlayout to a big number like 2000dp and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

The `ScrollView` will only scroll if its content is higher than its actual height. If the content can fit inside the height of the `ScrollView`, the `ScrollView` will never need to actually scroll.

Is your content higher than the height of your `ScrollView` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="generalclasses.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/signintextview"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/useridtext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usertextview"
                android:layout_below="@+id/usertextview"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/hintusuario" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usertextview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:text="@string/usertextview"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signupherebutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/signinbutton"
                android:text="@string/signupherebutton" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/passwordtextview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/useridtext"
                android:layout_below="@+id/useridtext"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="@string/passwordtextview"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordedittext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordtextview"
                android:layout_below="@+id/passwordtextview"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/hintsenha"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newheretextview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/signupherebutton"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/signupherebutton"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/signinbutton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:text="@string/newheretextview"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signinbutton"
                style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordedittext"
                android:layout_below="@+id/passwordedittext"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:text="@string/signinbutton" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this, Add your code inside Linear layout , it will Scroll till End of the Page.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

    // Your xml Code Put Here

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Relativelayout>
```